# Undefined function 'conv2' for input arguments of type 'double' and attributes 'full 3d real'. - Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I'm trying to filter an image in the space domain so i'm using the conv2 function.

here's my code.

```
cd /home/samuelpedro/Desktop/APIProject/

close all
clear all
clc

img = imread('coimbra_aerea.jpg');
%figure, imshow(img);

size_img = size(img);

gauss = fspecial('gaussian', [size_img(1) size_img(2)], 50);

%figure, surf(gauss), shading interp

img_double = im2double(img);

filter_g = conv2(gauss,img_double);
```

I got the error:

```
Undefined function 'conv2' for input arguments of type 'double' and attributes 'full 3d
real'.

Error in test (line 18)
filter_g = conv2(gauss,img_double);
```

now i'm wondering, can't I use a 3 channel image, meaning color image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Color images are 3 dimensional arrays (x,y,color).  `conv2` is only defined for 2-dimensions, so it won't work directly on a 3-dimensional array.

Three options:

- Use an n-dimensional convolution, `convn()`
- Convert to a grayscale image using `rgb2gray()`, and filter in 2D:

  `filter_g = conv2(gauss,rgb2gray(img_double));`
- Filter each color (RGB) separately in 2D:

  ```
  filter_g = zeros(size(im_double));
  for i = 1:3
    filter_g(:,:,i) = conv2(gauss, im_double(:,:,i);
  end
  ```

Comment: Filtering each color separately is a great idea. i didn't have thought of that. :)

Comment: If you want to do this faster, passing a multi-plane image to imfilter or since this question is doing gaussian filtering, to imgaussfilt, will be faster. Both of these functions know how to operate on multi-plane data without the use of a for loop. See my answer below for more info.

Answer (score 1):

For n-D input, you need to use `convn`.

Comment: well, i was afraid that would be the only chance. but convn turns matlab really slow.

Comment: @SamuelNLP: You can use `convn`, but with two 1-D Gaussian filters (one along X, the other along Y). That will speed up your code a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you have R2015a or newer, the IPT function imgaussfilt handles multi-plane 2-d convolution problems like this, just pass in your RGB image.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaussfilt.html

If you don't, imfilter also performs multiplane 2-d convolution.

Both will be faster for a Gaussian filter, they both know how to do the separable trick for you.

Comment: Also remove the im2double when using imgaussfilt/imfilter, both apply SIMD optimizations for integer inputs, so they'll be faster without the cast.